# Counting occurences in data frame based on multiple columns - R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, multiple-columns

I have a csv file game.csv. Here is the sample of the dataset

```
home   guest    result
team1  team2      w
team2  team3      l
team1  team3      l
```

How can I get the count of team1 wins when played at home ground in R language?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
sum(df$home == 'team1' & df$result == 'w')
```

which is similar to subsetting the dataframe and calculating number of rows.

```
nrow(subset(df, home == 'team1' & result == 'w'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `which/length`

```
length(which(df$home == 'team1' & df$result == 'w'))
```